# Evince Document Viewer gets stuck in full screen mode in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: evince

I am Using Ubuntu 20.04 on a computer that has 4 GB RAM and an Intel Core i5 Processor. When I open PDF files in Evince Document Viewer in full screen mode, sometimes it gets stuck. Neither getting input from the keyboard and mouse nor the screen moves. Is this a bug or is it just for my computer? If it is only for me, is there any fix for it?

Comment: You can try to look at syslog (`tail -f /var/log/syslog`) during the time of the event and add the relevant error messages logged there to your original question above...

Comment: have you tried super-arrowkeys, F, F11, alt-space then move/resize?